# Spring boot controller issue

Tags: spring, servlets, spring-boot, servlet-filters

I'm using a filter to check if the user is connected (token is valid) , if the token is not a valid  I set an attribute called "error" with the details of the error, here is my controller

```
@RestController
public class HomeController {


@RequestMapping(value = "secure/info", method = RequestMethod.POST)

public Object login(@RequestBody User user,@RequestAttribute(name="error") AppError error)  {

    if(error!=null) return error ;
    return "information";

}
```

And here is my filter :

```
        @Override
        public void doFilter(final ServletRequest req, final ServletResponse res, final FilterChain chain)
                throws IOException, ServletException {

            final HttpServletRequest request = (HttpServletRequest) req;
            final HttpServletResponse response = (HttpServletResponse) res;
            final String authHeader = request.getHeader("authorization");

            if ("OPTIONS".equals(request.getMethod())) {
                response.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_OK);

                chain.doFilter(request, response);
            } else {

                if (authHeader == null || !authHeader.startsWith("Bearer ")) {
                    AppError error = new AppError("0001","Invalid bearer token.");
                    request.setAttribute("error", error);
                    chain.doFilter(request, response);
                }

                final String token = authHeader.substring(7);

                try {
                    final Claims claims = Jwts.parser().setSigningKey("secretkey").parseClaimsJws(token).getBody();
                    request.setAttribute("claims", claims);
                } catch (final SignatureException e) {
                    AppError error = new AppError("0002","Invalid token signature.");
                    request.setAttribute("error", error);
                    chain.doFilter(request, response);
                }
                 catch (final ExpiredJwtException e) {
                     AppError error = new AppError("0003","Expired token.");
                     request.setAttribute("error", error);
                     chain.doFilter(request, response);

                 }

                 catch (final MalformedJwtException e) {
                     AppError error = new AppError("0004","Malformed token.");
                     request.setAttribute("error", error);
                     chain.doFilter(request, response);
                     //return ;
                 }



                chain.doFilter(req, res);
            }
        }
```

and here is the exception I get :

> java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot call sendError() after the
>   response has been committed
>         at org.apache.catalina.connector.ResponseFacade.sendError(ResponseFacade.java:472)
>   ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.16.jar:8.5.16]
>         at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.support.DefaultHandlerExceptionResolver.handleHttpMessageNotReadable(DefaultHandlerExceptionResolver.java:386)
>   ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar:4.3.10.RELEASE]
>         at ...
>             ....
>         at com.inconso.LoginFilter.doFilter(LoginFilter.java:67) [classes/:na]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Either **add a return statement** right after first `chain.doFilter(request, response);` -- Early return approach

```
                if (authHeader == null || !authHeader.startsWith("Bearer ")) {
                    AppError error = new AppError("0001","Invalid bearer token.");
                    request.setAttribute("error", error);
                    chain.doFilter(request, response);

                    // ADD a RETURN STATEMENT HERE
                }
```

OR (IF-ELSE Ladder Approach)

```
// START: MOVE THIS inside AN ELSE Block

                final String token = authHeader.substring(7);

                try {
                    final Claims claims = Jwts.parser().setSigningKey("secretkey").parseClaimsJws(token).getBody();
                    request.setAttribute("claims", claims);
                } catch (final SignatureException e) {
                    AppError error = new AppError("0002","Invalid token signature.");
                    request.setAttribute("error", error);
                    chain.doFilter(request, response);
                }
                 catch (final ExpiredJwtException e) {
                     AppError error = new AppError("0003","Expired token.");
                     request.setAttribute("error", error);
                     chain.doFilter(request, response);

                 }

                 catch (final MalformedJwtException e) {
                     AppError error = new AppError("0004","Malformed token.");
                     request.setAttribute("error", error);
                     chain.doFilter(request, response);
                     //return ;
                 }
// END: MOVE THIS inside AN ELSE Block
```

Answer (score 1):

In the `else` block where this condition is true: `authHeader == null || !authHeader.startsWith("Bearer ")` you are invoking `chain.doFilter()` twice.

Once in this block:

```
if (authHeader == null || !authHeader.startsWith("Bearer ")) {
    AppError error = new AppError("0001","Invalid bearer token.");
    request.setAttribute("error", error);
    chain.doFilter(request, response);
}
```

And the a second time at the end of the `else` block:

```
else {

    ...

    chain.doFilter(req, res);
}
```

Once is enough so either remove the last `chain.doFilter(request, response)` from the bottom of the else block or remove the `chain.doFilter(request, response)` from the if and catch clauses elsewhere in that block.